# Please solve $x+3^x <4$

Tags: inequality

I know it's simpler than what I'm making it out to be. I'm stuck and I forgot how to use logs. 
$x+3^x < 4$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @thesmallprint What do you mean by "try $x=1$. obviously that won't work ?? Actually it works

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Show that the function $x \mapsto x + 3^x$ is strictly increasing, that is if $x < y$, then also $x+3^x < x+3^y$, here you might use known properties of the logarithm function.

Step 2: Find an $x_0$ such that equality holds: $x_0 + 3^{x_0} = 4$.

Step 3: Combine 1 and 2 to see that $x + 3^x < 4$ if and only if $x < x_0$.